# Upgrading from .net core 1.1 to 2.0 changed [Produces("application/json")] behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have upgraded our project from .net core 1.1 to 2.0 and everything seems to be working fine except controller actions that are returning strings that are Json text. They look like

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Get(string name)
{
    var jsonStr = service.GetJsonStringFromDB();

    return Ok(jsonStr);
}
```

We have Json objects that are stored in the Db as text. In the old project our angular services would see this as Json data and we would get an object back, in the new project our Angular services are seeing it as strings and we get a string back. Nothing has changed client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually the correct behavior.

`Ok` is a helper method around `OkObjectResult` (in fact, all results which inherit from `ObjectResult` will try to deserialize it to the configured type, depending on which serializer are registered and which response type the client requests etc.) , which will **serialize** the input.

If you want to return raw strings, use `Content` instead.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Get(string name)
{
    var jsonStr = service.GetJsonStringFromDB();

    return Content(jsonStr);
    // Alternatively, pass the type here 
    //return Content(jsonStr, "application/json");
}
```